# Group By using Linq

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

I need to present a list of Ads grouped by category, including the Ads Count for each category.

Categories are grouped by a Parent Category like Cars that include the Categories Saloon, Cabriolet and Sports.

Models:

```
public class Ad
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Category Category { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CategoryParent")]
    public int? CategoryParent_Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Ad> Ads { get; set; }
}
```

The result as to be:

```
 Cars - Count: 100 (where 100 is the sum of for example 20 Saloon's Ads, 80 Cabrilet's)
```

At the moment, I'm only able to present the list of all Categories, and not grouped by Parent Category.

```
var adIds = {1,2,4,5}

var result = 
    from c in categoryQuery
    let searchCount = c.Ads.Count(a => adIds.Contains(a.Id))
    where searchCount > 0
    select new CategoryGetAllBySearchDto
    {
        Id = c.CategoryParent_Id,
        Name = c.CategoryParent.Name,
        SearchCount = searchCount,
        Ids = c.Ads.Where(a => adIds.Contains(a.Id)).Select(a => a.Id)
    };
```

Comment: I understood that for each category you want to know the sum of the number of items in both the category itself and all its successors categories (children, grandchildren, etc.). Is that correct? You also say that you want a list of items or groups of items. It is not very clear. Thank you specify. Your example shows the concept of count, but not a list of items.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. I want to group the categories by ParentCategory with the count of all ads of the child category. Like Cars: 100 (sum of saloons, cabriolets,etc) Bikes: 20 (sum of choppers, etc...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GroupBy` in memory:

```
var adIds = { 1, 2, 4, 5 };
var result = categoryQuery.Where(c => c.Ads.Any(a => adIds.Contains(a.Id)))
                        .Select(c => new 
                        { 
                            c.CategoryParent_Id, 
                            c.CategoryParent.Name,
                            Ids = c.Ads.Where(a => adIds.Contains(a.Id)).Select(a => a.Id).AsEnumerable()
                        })
                        .ToList()
                        .GroupBy(c => new {c.CategoryParent_Id, c.Name})
                        .Select(g => new CategoryGetAllBySearchDto
                         {
                             Id = g.Key.CategoryParent_Id,
                             Name = g.Key.Name,
                             Ids = g.SelectMany(u => u.Ids).AsEnumerable()
                         })
                         .ToList();
```

Comment: how much does this take in millisecond ?

Comment: Man your are good!! 150ms :P:P:P I think it's enought for me, or you can do better? Just kiding..;) Thank you for your help!

Comment: You to! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

i think you need this:

```
var adIds = { 1, 2, 4, 5 };
var result = from c in categoryQuery
             where c.Ads.Any(a => adIds.Contains(a.Id))
             group c by new {c.CategoryParent_Id, c.CategoryParent.Name} into g
             select new CategoryGetAllBySearchDto
             {
                 Id = g.Key.CategoryParent_Id,
                 Name = g.Key.Name,

                 SearchCount = g.SelectMany(u => u.Ads)
                                .Where(a => adIds.Contains(a.Id))
                                .Count(),

                 Ids = g.SelectMany(u => u.Ads)
                        .Where(a => adIds.Contains(a.Id))
                        .Select(a => a.Id)
             };
```

Comment: Hi thanks. I get "searchCount" don't exist in the current context in the line "SearchCount = searchCount", any idea why?

Comment: also you can get out the `SearchCount` to make your query simple, i need to post another answer

Comment: My older version where I was only listing the Category count and not the CategoryParent Grouping count was arount 150ms (Chrome time), and now it's 492ms for the same search :(

Comment: it is not the same, it has `GroupBy`, also you can fetch all data, and group them in momery,

Answer (score 1):

you can get out the `SearchCount` an add the `AsEnumerable` to `Ids` to get query just once

```
    public class CategoryGetAllBySearchDto
        {
            public int? Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }

            public int SearchCount { get {  return this.Ids.Count() } }

            public IEnumerable<int> Ids { get; set; }
        }
```

and the query :

```
var adIds = { 1, 2, 4, 5 };
        var result = from c in categoryQuery
                     where c.Ads.Any(a => adIds.Contains(a.Id))
                     group c by new {c.CategoryParent_Id, c.CategoryParent.Name} into g
                     select new CategoryGetAllBySearchDto
                     {
                         Id = g.Key.CategoryParent_Id,
                         Name = g.Key.Name,
                         Ids = g.SelectMany(u => u.Ads)
                                .Where(a => adIds.Contains(a.Id))
                                .Select(a => a.Id)
                                .AsEnumerable()
                     };
```

Comment: It's getting better! 266ms :P is this the best we can achieve in your opinion?

Comment: its because of `GroupBy`, you can do the `GroupBy` in memory, check my new post